# Condition in <ListItem> In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

How do i put a condition on the `<ListItem>` in React? This is to hide if the role isn't admin.

```
const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.auth.is_admin);


const drawer = (
  <div>
    <Divider />
    <List>
      {[
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Products',
          url: `/products`,
          access: false,
          icon: <DashboardIcon/>,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Settings',
          url: `/settings`,
          access: true,
          icon: <AssignmentTurnedInIcon/>,
        },
      ].map((obj, index) => (
<ListItem button key={obj.id} onClick={() => props.history.push(obj.url)} {isAdmin === obj.access}>
  <ListItemIcon>{obj.icon}</ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      disableTypography
      primary={
        <Typography type="body1" style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
          {obj.text}
        </Typography>
      }
    />
</ListItem>

))}
</List>
<Divider />
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your code to be something like this:

```
const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.auth.is_admin);

const ListItem = {[
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Products',
      url: `/products`,
      access: false,
      icon: <DashboardIcon/>,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Settings',
      url: `/settings`,
      access: true,
      icon: <AssignmentTurnedInIcon/>,
    },
  ].map((obj, index) => (
     obj.access === false && isAdmin || obj.access === true? 
<ListItem button key={obj.id} onClick={() => props.history.push(obj.url)} {}>
<ListItemIcon>{obj.icon}</ListItemIcon>
<ListItemText
  disableTypography
  primary={
    <Typography type="body1" style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
      {obj.text}
    </Typography>
  }
/>
</ListItem>
: ''

))}

const drawer = (
    <div>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {ListItem}
  </List>
  <Divider />
  </div>
  );
```

`access is false and isAdmin is true` is true when a menu is for the admin role, while `obj.access === true` when a menu is for all.

```
obj.access === false && isAdmin || obj.access === true
```

Comment: Pls check my edited question. I've changed a bit. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to put two values in access like access: true and false?

Comment: because if you're admin you can view all menus

Comment: @Robert I suggest you to not use boolean value, but to use costant values for roles in you application. Instead of access use grantedRole, an array of  users that are granted to access the menu. If the the user is an element of the array, then you visualize the menu.

Comment: The response of my api is like this user = {

isAdmin: true,
isCustomer: false

}, how will i access it?

Comment: What does access meaning? Is it access for user or for admin?

Comment: Some menu are just for regular users. But admin can access all menus. I just put access to each menu so i can compare it to the currently logged in user. You may want to change that to your idea.

Comment: ```access: false``` can it be accessed by the user? can it be accessed by the admin?

Comment: Just change the access to your  grantedUser: [admin], so it will be easier just like what you suggested. So how can i access it since the api has a result of  user = { isAdmin: true, isCustomer: false }

Comment: Do you get what i mean?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: You need to convert the user: { isAdmin: true, isCustomer: false }  to ARRAY because you have to check it like this grantedUser: [admin, customer], OR object is ok?

Comment: Hi. But i'm getting the value from the api like this user:{ isAdmin: true, isCustomer: false }, this should be check with the grantedUser: [admin]

Comment: The value of const userRole  is  user: { isAdmin: true, isCustomer: false }

Comment: I like your idea of using grantedUser: [admin. customer, user] But anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use ternary operator. Check if `isAdmin` is `true` then rendering the component, other case simply having `null`. Or if you have other condition like `isAdmin === 'admin'` then use that.

Try as the following:

```
return <>
   {
      isAdmin ?
        <ListItem button key={obj.id} onClick={() => props.history.push(obj.url)} />
      : null
   }
<>
```

Obviously I removed the other components for the sake of example. But this gives you the idea how to proceed further.

**+1 suggestion**:

`isAdmin` clearly shows me that has to be a `boolean` value, probably a different naming would be better like `role` or `userRole` in case if you are checking as a string with value `"admin"`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Pls check my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @Robert It's totally fine, just a suggestion.

Comment: How would i compare isAdmin to obj.access?

Comment: What type of value you have in `obj.access` and `isAdmin`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const isAdmin = useSelector((state) => state.auth.is_admin);


const drawer = (
  <div>
    <Divider />
    <List>
      {[
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Products',
          url: `/products`,
          access: false,
          icon: <DashboardIcon/>,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Settings',
          url: `/settings`,
          access: true,
          icon: <AssignmentTurnedInIcon/>,
        },
      ].map(obj => isAdmin === obj.access? (
<ListItem button key={obj.id} onClick={() => props.history.push(obj.url)}>
  <ListItemIcon>{obj.icon}</ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      disableTypography
      primary={
        <Typography type="body1" style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
          {obj.text}
        </Typography>
      }
    />
</ListItem>: ''

))}
</List>
<Divider />
</div>
);
```

Comment: put some details

Comment: Edited based on the refined question